# problema com while no tkinter

Tags: python, while, tkinter, gui

Olá estou com um pequeno problema na criação de um pequeno jogo. A ideia é rodar um numero aleatório e depois contar a rodada, o problema é na hora de contar a rodada. O while mantém sempre o maior numero da sequência. Eu tentei sem interface e deu certo, mas quando tem janela o programa da errado. Quem puder ajudar agradeço muito.

```
from tkinter import *
from random  import randint



janela=Tk()
janela.title("teste a sorte")
janela.geometry('300x200+200+200')
janela.visor=Label()
janela.rod=Label()


def cont():
 n=0
 while (n<10):
  result()
  janela.rod['text']="sua rodada é:", n
  janela.rod.pack(side="left")
  n+=1


 def result():

  janela.visor['text']=randint(0,2)
  janela.visor.pack(side="top")



def Aperte():

 janela.Bt=Button()
 janela.Bt['text']="clique e descubra seu numero"
 janela.Bt.pack(side="top")
 janela.Bt['command']=cont

Aperte()
janela=mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você quer que o joguinho tenha 10 rodadas apenas e que cada click seja uma rodada, certo?

Se estiver correto, o problema é que quando você clica no botão, ele chama a função `cont`. E no corpo dessa função você, todas as vezes, faz:

1. seta a variável n para zero.
2. escreve na janela 10 vezes (n == 9 no final disso)
3. programa volta ao repouso. Próximo clique o ciclo repete.

Você precisa fazer `n` uma variável global (basta declarar n = 0 antes de criar o objeto janela). O código de `cont` poderia ser assim:

```
def cont():
  global n
  
  if n > 10:
    return
  
  result()
  print(janela.visor['text'])
  janela.rod['text']="sua rodada é:", n
  janela.rod.pack(side="left")
  
  n += 1
```

Além disso, a função `result` deveria vir antes de `cont` já que a primeira é chamada no corpo da segunda.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nossa muito obrigado Walisson, eu já tava procurando a solução sem ver a alguns dias. Funcionou perfeitamente. Valeu